# How to return all values stored in memcache?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

How would one return all the values stored within the memcache?
I have tried using entrySet() and values() methods on the cache but both result in an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Ideally, I need to return all the entities stored within the cache and bulk save them to the datastore - is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Purely out of morbid curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a resource which is requested very frequently, this resource performs 3 datstore GETs and 3 PUTs. As a result I am using a huge number of datastore RPCs each day and want to reduce this.

My plan was to store entities in the memcache for a few minutes (updating the entities when needed) and then batch save these to the datastore. I'd then clear the cache and restart the process again.

Comment: As I mentioned on the other question, you really don't want to do that - there's a high chance you'll lose data.

Comment: I don't mind losing data every so often, I would rather reduce the number of datastore calls dramatically and risk losing data periodically than pay the huge fees I'm forecast.

If this is not possible fine, but if there is a way to implement a similar solution I'd love to hear it.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to read this blog post: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding

Comment: So basically in that example you use a task which runs at a specified interval. It subtracts the value of the counter in the datastore from the one in the memcache and then adds the difference to the value in the datastore. This is basically what I wish to achieve but I have a notable difference.

Comment: I am not dealing with an integer counter I have a memcache full of entities (of the same type), within each entity I have several integer counters. When the task is run (I've been using a cron job to initiate the "update" rather than a task), I need to persist all the entities in the memcache to the datastore and then clear the memcache. This is not the same as keeping a simple counter and accessing it with a given name/key. Am I missing the point or will your strategy work in my use-case? Thanks Nick.

Comment: The point is that you need to set up tasks per-key that you want to persist. You can't fetch all the values from the memcache, only specific ones.

Comment: I see. I don't have much experience with tasks so will have to have a closer look. Regardless, would it be advisable to have thousands of tasks scheduled to run to persist each entity after a few minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [`MemcacheService`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html) low-level documentation, I don't think it's possible to do so.

This is also supported by the [JCache Features Not Supported](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache.html#Features_Not_Supported) section of the docs:

> An app cannot dump the contents of the cache's keys or values.

(Note: I work for Google. but please don't take this as a response *from* Google. I haven't used AppEngine much myself.)

Comment: Jon's reading of the documention is correct. It's not possible to do at this time.